# Not able to submit Open Graph Action?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to submit open graph action.

Below is the text that I submitted to FB:

1. Click on this link:
   http://www.myatricleurllink/
   On the top of the article page, there is switch "on/off".
   This switch controls all Read actions within the app. 
   When user comes on the article page, switch is initially off.
   When user toggles the switch to "on", article will be published.
2. Use FB credentials for generating actions:
       dummy@gmail.com/dummy
3. When article is published, there will be a link "Remove from your reads" in two places:

   1. In article section.
   2. Just above the facebook comment social plugin.

   when user clicks "remove from your reads" link, posted article will be removed from user's  recent activity section.

But every time I am facing problem to submit action.

Below is the response from facebook:

We are unable to test this action according to the usage instructions you provided. Please provide thorough reproduction instructions and link(s) to a specific URL where we can trigger the action. You should also test your action to ensure you can successfully publish actions back to Auth Dialog Preview User's Timeline. Once you have made these changes, re-submit your action.
Please make changes below and resubmit for review.

Can somebody tell me, where I am wrong and what are the things that I need to do to approve facbook action.

Comment: Post the real link so that we can try to find the problem.

Comment: http://ec2-107-20-239-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/article/view/ten-reasons-why-crash-dieting-is-bad-for-you/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the 'Test User' feature in the 'Roles' section of the Facebook App Settings page, instead of providing Facebook with a Fake Facebook Account. The 'Test User' feature will let someone login into the test account by following a link instead of entering a email / password. It's also against Facebook Platform Policy to have fake Facebook accounts.

Also, have you tested that the OpenGraph Actions work with the test user your provided? Only admins / developers / testers listed on the 'Roles' page of your App Settings will be able to trigger the Action before it's approved.

Profile links to a article that someone can easily test on. This will make it easier for Facebook to test the action(s).

I was able to get my action approved in < 2 days by including the above information.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have tested OpenGraph Actions from developers/ testers accounts and It's working fine with them. While submitting action I am providing real developer account's information but still not able to submit action.

Comment: Include a test account link anyway. The person at Facebook testing this may be lazy and it's easier for them to login using a link. 

Resubmit the action with as much info as possible and see if it helps. It will only take a few days to get an answer. No harm in trying.